# Missing an absolute value sign after using trig sub on integral vs partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

The integral in question is as follows:

> $$ \int \frac{dx}{(x^2 - 1)^2} $$

This question is in a chapter about integration by partial fractions, but I wanted to try using trigonometric substitution
$$
\left\{\begin{align}
x &= \sec\theta \\
dx &= \sec\theta\tan\theta \,d\theta 
\end{align}\right.
$$
to solve it. What I did:
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dx}{(x^2 - 1)^2} 
&= \int \frac{\sec\theta\tan\theta \,d\theta}{\tan^4\theta} \\
&= \int \sec \theta \cot^3 \theta \,d\theta \\
&= \int \csc\theta \cot^2 \theta \,d\theta \\
&= \int \csc^3\theta \,d\theta 
- \int \csc \theta \,d\theta \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\csc \theta \cot \theta 
+ \frac{1}{2}\ln|\csc \theta - \cot \theta| 
- \ln|\csc \theta - \cot \theta| + C \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}(\csc \theta \cot \theta 
+ \ln|\csc \theta - \cot \theta|) + C 
\end{align}

I drew a triangle with $ x = \sec\theta $, with a hypotenuse of length $ x $ and adjacent of length $ 1 $, so I obtained $ \csc \theta = \frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 - 1}} $ and $ \cot \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2 - 1}} $. After I substituted these back in, I got

$$ = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 - 1}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2 - 1}} + \ln\left|\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2 - 1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2 - 1}}\right|\right) + C $$

$$ = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{t}{t^2 - 1} + \ln\left|\frac{t-1}{\sqrt{t^2 - 1}}\right|\right) + C $$

Now, the correct answer the book gave is

$$ \frac{1}{4}\left(\ln|t + 1| - \frac{1}{t+1} - \ln|t - 1| - \frac{1}{t - 1}\right) + C $$

I was able to use partial fraction decomposition on the $ \frac{t}{t^2 - 1} $  and properties of logarithms to get the same answer as given, however, I had to add an absolute value sign under the square root in order to get the correct absolute values inside the logarithms, i.e.

$$ \ln\left|\frac{t-1}{\sqrt{t^2 - 1}}\right| $$
had to be changed to
$$ \ln\left|\frac{t-1}{\sqrt{|t^2 - 1|}}\right| $$

I'm not sure why I missed this absolute value. Why did using trigonometric substitution produce an almost-correct answer, off by an absolute value sign in this case?

Comment: Note that $|\sec\theta|\geq 1$. In this range your solution is the same as the one given in your book.

Comment: @dfnu I see, so would a trigonometric substitution involving $ x = \sec \theta $ only produce an antiderivative that works for $ |x| \geq 1 $ ?

Comment: Definitely. For the other range you can write the denominator as $(1-x^2)^2$ and use $x=\sin\theta$.

Comment: @dfnu I think I got it - in the case of an integrand containing a square root in the denominator (e.g. $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} $), the domain of the integrand is automatically $ |x| < 1 $, so a substitution of $ x = \sin\theta \implies |x| \leq 1 $ works, but without the square root ($ \frac{1}{1 - x^2} $), the domain of the integrand is $ |x| \neq 1 $, so a seperate substitution or method would need to be used for the parts with $ |x| > 1 $, maybe $ x = \sec\theta \implies |x| \geq 1 $. Could you verify if that is correct?

Comment: Yes, the domain of the integrand is the union of two disjoint intervals, which in general requires a bit of care in expressing all the primitives, independently of the method you wish to use (consider, e.g., the fact that for each interval you can choose different additive constants). Should you decide to use a substitution, it is not necessary to use different substitution methods, though. This depends on the range and domain of the functions you use in the substitution. For example, in your case you could use $x = \sinh t$, to get a unique result for both intervals.

Answer (score 0):

**Integration by parts**

To avoid being troubled by the convention between trigonometric functions, we can try to integrate by parts.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{\left(x^2-1\right)^2}&=-\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{x} d\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right) \\
& =-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{x}{x^2-1}+\int \frac{1}{x^2-1} d x\right] \\
& =-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{x}{x^2-1}+\frac{1}{2} \ln \left|\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right|\right]+C \\
& =-\frac{x}{2\left(x^2-1\right)}+\frac{1}{4} \ln \left|\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!